# How To Pass Data From Google Drive API Into Rails App Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, google-drive-api

There is a simple Rails app form view. The user chooses via a "file-chooser feature" (e.g. Google Picker) a file from his API account (e.g. Google Drive account), and the API sends back data (url, thumbnails, ...) via a javascript callback function (see the JS code below).

How can you pass such data that comes from an API via a javascript callback function into a Rails model?

How does the code look like that ends up in the Rails _form file? What happens in the controller?

Sorry, I am quite new to Rails, and this might be a Rookie question. Any kind of suggestion, links where to read more about it etc. would be really helpful. I was searching for quite a while, but had no luck to find s.th. useful. 
Thank you so much for helping out!

The html/javascript:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" id="gdrive" onclick="javascript:openPicker()">
Choose Google Drive File
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  // The API developer key obtained from the Google Cloud Console.
  var developerKey = '<DEV KEY>';

  // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker.
  function openPicker() {
    gapi.load('picker', {'callback': createPicker});
  }

  // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
  function createPicker() {
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
        addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
        setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
        setCallback(pickerCallback).
        build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  }

  // A simple callback implementation.
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
    document.getElementById('gdrive').innerHTML = message;
  }
</script>  

<!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
```

An example Rails model:

```
  create_table "postfiles", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "gdrive"
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end
```

Again, thanks a lot for reading. Any ideas really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

Set up a hidden_field in the _form view:

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :gdrive,
                     :id => "gdrive"%>
```

and pass the data from the javascript callback function to the hidden_field via .setAttribute.

Here is the edited javascript part from above:

```
 // A simple callback implementation.
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    }
    document.getElementById('gdrive').setAttribute('value', url);
  }
```

The last line above sends the API data (here: url=doc[google.picker.Document.URL] ) to your rails model.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to save of course you can pass the values in url but you can also use some sort of hidden fields and then send it in form.

Comment: To keep it simple, let's say I would like to save just the URL that comes via the API --- url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL]; --- and save it in the Rails model "gdrive".